# What is to stop a developer from getting multiple API keys

Tags: web-services, api, language-agnostic

Most APIs ask developers to get an API key. The API key is then used for rate limiting. What is to stop a developer from getting multiple API keys as a way to prevent the rate limit?

The problem I'm facing is deciding how to issue an API key. The only thing I found working is to issue more of a "developer key".

- I haven't found a way to really rate limit an application's usage (someone could obtain multiple keys and sequence feed them to his app to get higher rates for this one app)
- and I haven't found a way to keep the key per-application (someone could get the key and use it on multiple domains)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**An API key isn't the right tool for rate limiting**, especially if the API is back-end callable.  It works if the code is integrated at the end-user's browser, since that serves as "neutral ground" that can ensure that the application identity isn't being spoofed, but not if it's called from a service or application written by your client developers.

**Resource utilization control is an economic problem**, so it calls for an economic solution.  Requiring a unique [**hashcash**](http://hashcash.org/) token per-call is a good way to enforce this.  (Hashcash is a proof-of-work scheme -- it requires the caller to prove they've expended a bunch of CPU time on a pointless task as a way to prove the request has value to them.)

It is also **scalable depending on load** -- if your service is being overwhelmed, you can dynamically increase the "price" in leading zero bits required in the token; each increase by one bit will reduce the request rate by half.  (Just make sure your API can communicate the hashcash "price" if it is dynamic.)

Comment: I'm wondering, how could one make an API that's not "back-end callable"?

Comment: @silow I'm thinking of something like Google Maps, where the public API is part of an embeddable interactive application that runs in the browser; the HTTP API between the Google Maps JavaScript component and the Google back-end servers is non-public.